# Are there .NET Core variants of the cryptographic CNG classes

Tags: c#, cng

Porting an existing Framework application to Core in which we had long since replaced `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256` and `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed` with the `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng`.  Is there a .net core equivalent of these `*Cng` types?  If not does are the same security issues present in core that were present in Framework?

Comment: There is a nuget package called `System.Security.Cryptography.Cng` which might be what you're looking for. The class `SHA256Cng` still doesn't exists but there is some equivalent like `CngAlgorithm.Sha256`

Comment: Cng is a windows thingy so presumably plattform dependant. Is that ok.

Comment: @Ralf I understand that it is windows specific and I likely should have worded the question as is the windows implementation of SHA256 based off of CryptoApi or Cng.

Comment: @PhilippApe Very helpful.  Is there official documentation that describes this behavior?

Comment: Of course. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-mode

Comment: @PhilippApe my google-fu failed me earlier.  if you want to post an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, since .NET 5 there aren't any differences any more. All these classes are now wrappers for the corresponding **FIPS certified OS implementation**. If there isn't any FIPS certified library installed for the current OS, a fallback library is choosen, even if it's not certified. Lastly a "Managed" implementation (purely C#) is choosen when available. If managed is also not available then an exception will be thrown.

A full explanation can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptography-model).
**Update**: Fixed link

Comment: This link doesn't work for me at least. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography seems to be a better link with all necessary details.

Comment: Can I use .net 5 CNG api to talk to HSM for key creation ?